# Calculate total price inside php table

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to show total price in a table.

I have 2 arrays where one is the names of the cars and second is the prices of each one.

I've managed do display the prices and the names inside the table,
but the thing is that i have a "checkbox" thing that shows if car is sold or not...

I'm trying to make the total calculation that calculate the total price of all checked checkboxes.

That means - when checkbox is on, the variable of total price should add that car's price to it.

here is how it should looks like:
[image: table example]

I must mention that I've just started to learn `php` at collage,
here's the array and the variable:

```
<?php  
    $cars = array ("ford","fiat","renault","mazda");
    $prices = array(100,80,90,120);
    $sold = '<input type="checkbox" name="sold">';
?>
```

I added up basic `style` for my table (in the same `php` file)

```
<style>

    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 8px;``
    }
</style>
```

and the `php` code for the table:

```
<?php  
    $cars = array ("ford","fiat","renault","mazda");
    $prices = array(100,80,90,120);
    $sold = '<input type="checkbox" name="sold">';
?>

<h1>list of cars</h1>
<table>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>sold</th>
     <?php
        for($i=0;$i<count($cars);$i++){
            echo 
            "<tr>
            <td>$cars[$i]</td>.
            <td>$prices[$i]$</td>.
            <td>$sold</td>.
            </tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

How can I calculate the amount of all checked checkboxes prices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: please fix my english if needed.

please notice that the hole code is written in single php file.
after quit a bit of time, i was mange to fix my code.
first, as suggest here before, the JS code that was given was written in jquery, i haven't learned that part of js yet, therefor i wrote the code with the help of my friend in js using dom.

CSS:

```
<style>
    
    body {
    text-align:center;}

    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top:15%;
    }
    
    th{
        
    }

    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
    tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
</style>
```

JS: (the location of the script tag doesn't matter at this point, but iv'e located it at the top of the php file inside header content.

```
<script>
  function calcTotal() {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        let priceAsStr  = document.getElementById("price" + index).innerHTML;
        let price = parseInt(priceAsStr);
        let soldOrNot = document.getElementById("soldOrNot" + index).checked;
        if (soldOrNot == true)
        {
           sum = sum + price;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML ="$" + sum;
  }
```

and finally, for the body:

```
<?php
    $cars = array("Ford","Fiat","Renault","Mazda");
    $prices = array(100,80,137,453);  
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Cars</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Sold</th>
   </tr>
   
 <?php
    $sum = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) { 
        echo "<tr id='row$i'>
        <td>{$cars[$i]}</td>
        <td id='price{$i}'> {$prices[$i]}$</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='soldOrNot{$i}' name='sold{$i}' onClick='calcTotal()' value=''> </td>
        </tr>";
    }
    
 ?>
</table>
<h1>Total Price: <span id="sum">0</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the checkbox to include the price as a data-attribute and put it within the for loop not outside of it.

```
$sold = '<input type="checkbox" data-price="$prices[$i]" name="sold">';
```

then in javascript just loop through the checkboxes and an event listener that checks for checked.

```
 function showTotal(els) {
  total = 0;
  els.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.checked) {
      total += +el.getAttribute("data-price");
    }
  });

  document.querySelector("#total").innerHTML = "$" + total.toFixed(2)
}

sold = document.querySelectorAll("[name='sold']");

sold.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("change", function(ev) {
    showTotal(sold)
  });
});
```

to show the total you will need a div to hold the total

```
<div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: how to i make the final result to appear at php page ? i've done the steps as you've suggested but i cant figure it out how to do so

Comment: @moses I updated my answer to include updated javascript and the div for showing the total.

Answer (score 0):

imvain2’s answer would be your best choice as it does not require a client-server roundtrip.

However, if you would like to do this in php, you need to associate the checkbox with the car in some way.

One way would be to tweak your for loop like so

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($cars); $i++) {
    echo (
        "<tr>
            <td>{$cars[$i]}</td>
            <td>{$prices[$i]}$</td>
            <td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"sold[]\" value=\"{$prices[$i]}\"></td>
        </tr>"
    );
}
```

So when the form containing the table is submitted to the server you can do the calculation like

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($_POST['sold'] as $value) {
    $total += (int)$value;
}
```